# Not able to connect to local MySQL install after using Docker and MySQL image to connect to secondary DB on external drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql, docker

Huge appreciation for help in advance.  Using Ubuntu 22.04 and MySQL 8.

I have a legacy MySQL DB on an external hard drive as well as a local install on my Ubuntu machine, both using MySQL 8.

I set up a Docker container and [MySQL image](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) to connect to the legacy DB in order to dump data for use elsewhere.  This worked without issue but now I'm not able to connect to my existing local MySQL installation.

The standard call to start MySQL returns an error stating it can't connect through socket:

```
chris@chris-X1C6:/etc/mysql$ mysql -u admin -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I've checked the the server is running, done a restart of MySQL and a restart of the system all to no avail.  Have also edited configuration files (`/etc/mysql/my.cnf`) to specify the location of a socket file (where a .sock file actually exists) and attempted to create symbolic link between the specified `/tmp/mysql.sock` file and the actual location of the sock file as part of the local installation (`/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock`).  None of this allows me to connect, with error message now reading:

```
chris@chris-X1C6:/etc/mysql$ mysql -u admin -p
Enter password:
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)
```

It took some trial and error to be able to access the data on external drive (ie, specifying where the data was located within Docker) so I likely inadvertently connected to the MySQL image through Docker while it was still pointed at my local install directory.  Not sure if/how this would mess up settings/config, but have only not been able to connect since using Docker so wonder how it may be related.

**Any thoughts on resolving or debugging are much appreciated.**

Answer (score 0):

I kinda don't understand why have you set up a new Docker container prior, I do understand a switch to containers.
You should used `mysqldump` in order to create a database dump and then use the following command below to restore it in the container:

```
cat dump.sql | docker exec -i <container_name> mysql --protocol tcp -uroot -p<rootpw> yourdbname
```

For the sock stuff you can just use TCP listening and listen on localhost and connect with mysql `-h` parameter like:

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -uroot -p
```

Database dump is also pretty easy:

```
mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases > dump.sql
```

or

```
mysqldump -uroot -p yourdbname > dump.sql
```

Comment: Thanks...specifying host ip does allow me to access the local install.  I've never needed to specify this when connecting before though, any idea what would have caused the change

Comment: You provide too little configuration to actually be able to find the cause. Perhaps you mount the socket file from the container in the same exact place where the old socket file is supposed to be? Maybe. You can always change your desired socket file location and use the new one. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33378573/12445681) on Stack Overflow - it tells you where your current socket file on which DB listens is.

Comment: Thanks...have changed socket location in cnf file, but still get 'Cant connect' error (as evidenced above).

Comment: What's the error code in the brackets?
`through socket '[...]/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (13)` means most likely that the sock file has invalid permissions as 13 means usually permission denied.
The first example with 2 means "no such file or directory".
You can find these codes by running `errno -l`.

Comment: `/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service` says that the service works on mysql:mysql permissions so it should match. Check what User= and Group= permissions are for mysql in your service file (if they exist, otherwise it's root:root but I guess it's mysql:mysql).